# Not able to access Private key from PKCS12 file using java

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, jks

I have created a pkcs12 file having a private key entry without any password.
I am able to access the p12 file using keytool utility without providing any password.

The same I am not able to to programmatically.
When I am trying like below

```
if( keyStore.isKeyEntry(KEYSTORE_ALIAS)) {
    key = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(KEYSTORE_ALIAS,new char[0]);
}
```

I am getting the below exception

```
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not
properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore.implDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:355)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore$PBEWithSHA1AndDESede.engineDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:387)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:266)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: The Java `keytool` program will not let you create a KeyStore unless you enter a password with a length of 6 or more characters.  How did you generate your private key?

Comment: Reformatted the stacktrace to avoid line wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

```
key = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(KEYSTORE_ALIAS,new char[0]);
```

That's not the correct way to specify no key. Here you are specifying a zero-length key. It isn't the same thing. Try this:

```
key = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(KEYSTORE_ALIAS, null);
```